# Update part of Object and send it back

Tags: javascript, json

I get a json object as below from an api

```
[
    {
        userId: 1,
        title: "title1",
        body: "body1"
    },
    {
        userId: 2,
        title: "title2",
        body: "body2"
    },
    {
        userId: 4,
        title: "title4",
        body: "body4"
    }
]
```

How is it possible to update only one user, for e.g. userId 4 i.e. partially updating the json object.

I know i can update the user by its id separately but what I want to achieve is update only partial part of json and want to post the whole object back.

Something like git does, update or add the specific line or user.

I hope you can understand what I meant. Please let me know if I am not clear. 
Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can manipulate array using `Array.map` operator. So,

```
const updatedArray = YourArray.map((element, index, array) => {
   if (element.userId === 4) {
      // do something with this element
   }
});
```

`Array.map` operator will return mutated array.

Answer (score 1):

```
let myArray = [ { userId: 1, title: "title1", body: "body1" },
                { userId: 2, title: "title2", body: "body2" },
                { userId: 4, title: "title4", body: "body4" }
              ];

objIndex = myArray.findIndex((obj => obj.userId == 4)); 
myArray[objIndex].title = "updatedTitle";
myArray[objIndex].body = "updatedBody";
console.log("Updated object: ", myArray[objIndex])
```

Comment: brilliant solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [
{
    userId: 1,
    title: "title1",
    body: "body1"
},
{
    userId: 2,
    title: "title2",
    body: "body2"
},
{
    userId: 4,
    title: "title4",
    body: "body4"
}
];

function findUserIdIs4(element) {
 return element.userId === 4;
};

const foundIndex = arr.findIndex(findUserIdIs4);

arr[foundIndex].title = "newTitle";

console.log(arr[foundIndex])
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, for such purposes, you would want to have your JSON structured like so:

```
const data = {
  1:{
    userId: 1,
    title: "title1",
    body: "body1"
  },
  2:{
    userId: 2,
    title: "title2",
    body: "body2"
  },
  4:{
    userId: 4,
    title: "title4",
    body: "body4"
  }
}
```

Then you can update specific "user":

```
data[4]["body"] = "body4 updated value"
```

Comment: Your second snippet would throw error because body is undefined. You need to put body in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

one best way is using array.map function.